# missing 1 required positional argument in curve_fit even though i pass all of them through

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a function and I can't get it to not appear with the error:

`TypeError: fft_fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lam'`

Even when I remove the p0 guess it still has this error. Using Juypter. It is always the last argument that is 'missing'. Help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
def fft_fit(f, f0, A, C, lam):
    return C + A / np.sqrt(lam**4 + (f**2 - f0**2)**2 + 2*lam**2 *(f**2 - f0**2))

y = np.fft.rfft(np.real(yfilt)) 
nn = y.size
f = np.linspace(0, (nn/ tmax), nn)

yfit, cov = curve_fit(fft_fit, f, np.real(y), p0=[307.00693, 1.96401, 1, 1/0.252193])
```

Comment: works fine for me. Unfortunately your example is incomplete, so I had to modify/add some code to let it run here. Try to provide a complete example that reproduces the error.